# C# Set ListBox width so that longest item fits

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I would like to set my ListBox.Width property so that it is no wider nor narrower than needed, in order to display the items in it. There is a margin of a few pixels between the left of the ListBox and the start of the text - I would like there to be a similar margin on the right. (i.e. there shouldn't be a large gap, and the letters shouldn't be touching the right edge).

Given that I'm not sure how many pixels a given string will be, I'm not sure how to calculate this width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the MeasureString method of the Graphics class.

Try this:

```
Graphics graphics = this.createGraphics();
SizeF mySize = graphics.MeasureString("Ahoy there", this.Font);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want. Also play around with Integral Height and padding.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/resizablelistbox.aspx

Comment: My link implements @Fishz 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it wasn't until I changed the width of the listbox that I saw the results I wanted.  I looped through the items in the listbox to get the longest.  Hope this helps.

```
int LongestItemLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count;i++ ){
    Graphics g = listBox1.CreateGraphics();
    int tempLength = Convert.ToInt32((
            g.MeasureString(
                    listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), 
                    this.listBox1.Font
                )
            ).Width);
    if (tempLength > LongestItemLength){
        LongestItemLength = tempLength;
    }
}
listBox1.Width = LongestItemLength;
listBox1.Show();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `CreateGraphics()` on each iteration of the loop? Also, you aren't disposing the `Graphics` objects you create. Simply for `Graphics.MeasureString()`, I believe any `Graphics` object will do! No need to re-create.